# Restrict permissions to cherry-pick

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

After a particular release, any bugfixes will go into 'master' branch and after it is thoroughly reviewed and tested, it will be cherry-picked to the release branch. However I want only the release manager(..one who manages the release) to have access to cherry-pick those changes to release branch. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Git doesn't have branch permissions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248246/git-branch-permissions

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6646792/283084 for information on software supporting permission schemes in git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git doesn't have branch permissions, but folder permissions would let you give only the manager access to a 'release' clone of the repo. The manager pulls changes in, merges them into their release branch locally, then pushes to the release repo. You could give everyone read access from this one, so they could stay in parity with the release branch.